# is it possible to have an ahk script interval for less than a millisecond?

Tags: autohotkey

```
pause

#Persistent
SetTimer, PressTheKey, 1
Return

PressTheKey:
Send, {\}
Return


F1::

pause
```

This is what I have so far. I use the script to help me make ASCII art faster. is it possible to make the interval faster...less than 1 millisecond?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, there is no unit smaller than 1ms when dealing with timers. You could just use a loop in place of a timer, or try changing the SetBatchLines value: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetBatchLines.htm